# Sizing pseudo element image to match container

Tags: html, css, less, pseudo-element

I have been trying to add a pseudo-element image to a title heading. I have managed to get it to display in the locations I want but I am really struggling to get the image to scale dynamically with the heading size. So when the heading is a H1 the image is fine but reducing the heading to say a H5 the image remains the same size and overlaps into other content.

Example of the problem:

---

[image]

---

The HTML:

```
<h1 class="title brand" id="id">some content <small>a sub header</small></h1>
<h5 class="title brand reverse" id="id">some content <small>a sub header</small></h5>
```

The LESS:

```
/*
 * Headers
 */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 font-family: @font-family-emphasis;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: .75em 0;
 display: block;
}

h1 {
 font-size: @font-size-h1;
}

h2 {
 font-size: @font-size-h2;
}

h3 {
 font-size: @font-size-h3;
}

h4 {
 font-size: @font-size-h4;
}

h5 {
 font-size: @font-size-h5;
}

h6 {
 font-size: @font-size-h6;
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
 strong {
  font-weight: 500;
 }

 &.light {
  font-weight: 200;
 }

 &.title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px @color-interface-grey-light;
 }

 &.page-title {
  border-bottom: solid 1px @color-interface-grey;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
 }

 .small,small {
  color: darken( @color-interface-grey, 25% );
  font-size: .65em;
 }

 &.brand {
  padding: .5em 0 .5em;
  margin: 0.5em 0 .5em 2.5em;
  &:after{
   content: url("../img/brand-mark.svg");
   position: absolute;
   left:0.5em;
  }

 &.reverse {
  padding: .5em 0 .5em;
  margin: 0.5em 2.5em .5em 0em;
  &:after{
   content: '';
  }
  &:before{
    content: url("../img/brand-mark-reverse.svg");
    position: absolute;
    right:0.5em;
  }
 }
}
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you set the height to 100%? or set it as a background image and then use background-size property

Comment: @Pete I was able to build a solution using the background-size property, so your intution was right on that point.  Using a 100% height does not seem to work since the content is not treated as an inline replaced element, so the usual tricks don't apply since pseudo-elements are outside the regular content flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it if you can place your icon image as a backround to the pseuodo elements.

This technique relies on CSS3 properties, specifically, `background-size: contain`.

You may need to specify a width value for the pseudo-element depending on your design.

```css
h1, h5 {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
h1:after, h5:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 50px; /* Tweak this value as needed... */
  background: url(http://placehold.it/50x50) no-repeat right bottom / contain;
}
```

```html
<h1>some content <small>a sub header</small></h1>
<h5>some content <small>a sub header</small></h5>
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I had looked at background size but only as fixed sizes, I wasn't aware of the contain option. Works brilliantly.